# How does ActionScript BitmapData generate perlin noise?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, perlin-noise

The "classical" algorithm has 2 additional parameters, except for octaves, namely scale and persistence. Basically I have an actionscript code, that generates perlin noise and I need to implement the same with JavaScript. JS implementation has 2 additional parameters, so I'm not really sure if I can implement exactly the same noise with JS library.